# Kubernetes with Traefik v2.5 basic setup on Windows - cannot access Traefik dashboard and 2nd component

Tags: kubernetes

Inspired by [this nice article](https://www.kubetools.io/kubernetes/using-traefik-v2-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-kubernetes-a-step-by-step-guide-for-developers-and-kubernetes-enthusiasts/) I tried to setup a very basic Traefik environment on Kubernetes. I know this is the minimum setup without security, etc. We use Traefik for many years on Docker Swarm and want to move on to Kubernetes.

In short: this is the basic traefik yml file with deployment, service and ingressroute:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: traefik
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: traefik
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: traefik
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: traefik
        image: traefik:v2.5
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        - name: admin
          containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik
spec:
  selector:
    app: traefik
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  - name: admin
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: admin
  type: NodePort
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: traefik-web-ui
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
  - match: PathPrefix(`/dashboard`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: traefik
      port: 8080
```

The NgInx yaml is:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
  - match: PathPrefix(`/nginx`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: nginx
      port: http
```

Applying I do with:

```
$ kubectl apply -f traefik.yaml
$ kubectl apply -f nginx.yaml
```

All is running:

[image]

[image]

Browsing to either http://localhost/dashboard, http://localhost/dashboard/, http://localhost/nginx or http://localhost/nginx/  gives no result but ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Comment: Did you try accessing on http://<node_IP>:31268 or 31330 ? just to confirm that the node port service is working.

Comment: No response, alas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you **Fayezk13**! You showed me the way to streamline my search on the internet.

Based on the 'helm install' way I found 3 ways for routing traffic via Traefik v2. I hope you can appreciate the results of hours searching on the internet.

**1. Via Ingress**

An example is:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: whoami-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /whoami
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: whoami
                port:
                  name: web
```

**2. Via IngressRoute (traefik.io/v1alpha1)**

You first have to load the CRD from the Traefik site.

An example is:

```
apiVersion: traefik.io/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: default
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - match: PathPrefix(`/nginx`)
      kind: Rule
      middlewares:
        - name: nginx-stripprefix
      services:
        - name: nginx
          port: 80
---
apiVersion: traefik.io/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: nginx-stripprefix
spec:
  stripPrefix:
    prefixes:
      - /nginx
```

**3. Via traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1.**

You first have to load the CRD from the Traefik site.

An example:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: nginx3
  namespace: default
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - web
  routes:
    - kind: Rule
      match: PathPrefix(`/third`)
      middlewares:
        - name: nginx3-stripprefix
      services:
        - name: nginx
          port: 80
    - kind: Rule
      match: PathPrefix(`/fourth`)
      middlewares:
        - name: nginx4-pathreplace
      services:
        - name: nginx
          port: 80
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: nginx3-stripprefix
spec:
  stripPrefix:
    prefixes:
      - /third
---
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: Middleware
metadata:
  name: nginx4-pathreplace
spec:
  replacePathRegex:
    regex: ^/fourth/(.*)
    replacement: /third/$1
```

Answer (score 2):

I would drop this method of deploying Traefik.

The official way is much more easier to deploy and manage:

1. Install the helm chart

```bash
helm repo add traefik https://traefik.github.io/charts
helm repo update
helm install traefik traefik/traefik
```

2. Expose the dashboard

```bash
kubectl port-forward $(kubectl get pods --selector "app.kubernetes.io/name=traefik" --output=name) 9000:9000
```

3. Access on http://127.0.0.1:9000/dashboard/